# Scala.JS: How to enforce fastOptJS - when running tests

Tags: sbt, scala.js

When I run my server tests it always runs a full optimization on the client module. (`server/test`)

I tried different things to enforce to use only fast optimization, without success.

Even `scalaJSStage in Global := FastOptStage` did not help.

**Is there a way to achieve that?**

I use `scalatest`for testing.

It is a Play-project and the following `scala-js` plugins I use:

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js"     % "sbt-scalajs"              % "0.6.21")
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-native" % "sbt-crossproject"         % "0.2.2")  
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-native" % "sbt-scalajs-crossproject" % "0.2.2")
```

Comment: Which test framework do you use? Probably solution doesn't depend on it, but I used μtest and it ran `fastOptJS`.

Comment: I added more infos to my questions